# Dynamically adding select/options in javascript not working with IE

Tags: javascript, dynamic

This code works fine in Firefox but not in IE version 9:
      var numLocations = Lookup_EngineLocations ( value, strState, strTown )

```
  var catOptions = "";
  var x          = 0;
  var newSel     = document.getElementById ( "LOCATIONS" );
  var opt;

  newSel.innerHTML = "<option value='0'>Select</option>";

  alert ( "Got here with " + newSel.innerHTML);

  for ( x=0; x < numLocations; x++ )
     {
     opt = document.createElement("option");
     opt.value = strLocationsID        [x];
     opt.text  = strLocationsLOCATIONS [x];

     newSel.appendChild ( opt );
     }

  alert ( "Got here with " + newSel.innerHTML);
  alert ( "Got here with " + document.getElementById ( "LOCATIONS" ).innerHTML);
```

Both alert() calls provide the right stuff but the dropdownlist contains all empty things, even though I am clearly adding a value and a text element.

Jerry

Comment: opt.text should be opt.innerText

Comment: There's no `.text` on DOM elements. That stops your script. Use `.innerText` or `.textContent`.